# How to run a Batch script on all connected Computers with Admin rights (Windows 7)

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, windows-7, system

I have  a Simple Script to create a user and add it to administrators localgroup in a local computer:

```
NET USER admin password /ADD
NET LOCALGROUP administrators admin /ADD
```

I'd like to create a script that copy & execute my file (or execute the commands above) in **every** available computer in my LAN network. i have admin right to do it manually. but i would very like to automate the process of adding user + give it admin privileges with shell script.

p.s.

1. If there is another way to do it with CMD / PowerShell it would be great.
2. I don't have access to the internet so third party programs are not an option.

Comment: This question should be moved to serverfault. Use Group Policy to manage the membership of the local `Administrators` groups on computers.

Comment: I tried using this script manually on each computer so far.
Sadly, I don't know how to use Group Policy nor if I can use it at all..

Comment: @gvee i tried to run console program in C# which execute schecule taks to run my script on each computer, that is after i copied the script to all connected endpoints